# 500 http sessions result in low database connection utilization

Tags: sql-server, performance, tomcat6, alfresco, java-6

We have an Alfresco server running on Tomcat6 and a look at the manager/html page tells us that there are approx. 500 active http session during an usual workday.

Is it normal/expected that this kind of load only utilizes **one** of the 8 open jdbc-connections?
I would expect that there is a lot more load on the database as all the node metadata cannot already be in the ehcache.

My assumption would be that there is load on approx 30 DB connections.

Am I completely wrong on this?

```
Alfresco 4.0.2.9, Tomcat6, Java6, Window Server 2008R2, MSSQL

#alfresco-global.properties
db.pool.initial=30
db.pool.max=300
db.pool.idle=-1
hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size=150
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTTP, 500 simultaneous connections is not really that many. Remember that HTTP 1.1 keeps the connection open after the current request or requests, to make subsequent requests faster, so these are not necessarily doing anything.

Rather than simultaneous connections, you should consider how many simultaneous ***requests*** there are - where the server is processing two requests simultaneously. Only then is there a reason to use more than one database connection.

Comment: Thanks for responding Ben! How would I best measure simultaneous requests? I have access to JavaMelodi on that server and in the "http hits per minute - 1 day" widget it shows me that there were a "Mean 197" and "Maximum 1271" requests/minute to day so far.

Comment: Does it tell you the mean duration of each request? I.e. the server response time? 1271 is only about 20 per second and 197 is less than four per second. If it takes less than a 20th of a second to service a request then they will rarely overlap. If those are your stats I am not surprised you aren't using multiple simultaneous database connections.